# Error in sending mail through outlook using VB

Tags: vba

I am verymuch new to VB. I am getting error no 287 (Application defined or object defined error)whil sending email from excel (outlook 2010).
I have set  Tool->option

Advance thanks for your kind help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If you don't post the code you're using, how do you expect anyone to tell you what you're doing wrong? We can't see your screen (or read your mind) from here, so the only information we have is what you give us in your question. Please edit your question to include the actual code you're using (and the **exact** error message you're getting) so someone here can try and help you. Thanks. :)

Comment: If your new to VB and wokring with outlook then it's essential to check out the forums on (http://www.outlookcode.com)

Answer (score 1):

In order to send an email message from excel via outlook, you would have to set an refrence to outlook in Excel VBA

Tools -> Refrences -> "Microsoft Outlook 12.0 Object Library"

Then you have to use a similar code written in excel vba to send mail using outlook

[Mail worksheet in the body of the mail](http://www.rondebruin.nl/mail/folder3/mail2.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, swap out the xlsm  file named low margin with your file.  Change the name of the sheet in the code to your files sheet.   put your email in.
Remember there's a difference between "this workbook" and "module1"
also to get around the outlook pop up I used send keys to hit the send button.  `alt+f+e=%fe`

```
This Workbook


Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Run "Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body"
End Sub


Module1

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "/" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    ' Copy the range and create a workbook to receive the data.
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    ' Publish the sheet to an .htm file.
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         FileName:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    ' Read all data from the .htm file into the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.ReadAll
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    ' Close TempWB.
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    ' Delete the htm file.
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function


Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()
    ' You need to use this module with the RangetoHTML subroutine.
    ' Works in Excel 2000, Excel 2002, Excel 2003, Excel 2007, Excel 2010, Outlook 2000, Outlook 2002, Outlook 2003, Outlook 2007, and Outlook 2010.

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    ' You can also use a sheet name here.
    Set rng = Sheets("Change to sheet name of xslm file").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = "your email"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Low Margin Pricing Alert"
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
            ' In place of the following statement, you can use ".Display" to
            ' display the e-mail message.
        .Display
        Application.SendKeys "%(FE)", True
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub
```