# excel VBA Replace text in Outlook OFT file from excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, outlook-2010

In excel I have three columns:

```
A:        B:               C:
UserName  UsermailAddress  RecordToBeDeleted
```

I'm using the code below in excel to send and email from Outlook (using an OFT file) to each of the email addresses in Column B of the excel spread sheet.

The code I have works as far as sending to each of the email addresses in Column B

The problem I have is that in the email message (the OFT file) I have two keywords (`UserName` and `RecordToBeDeleted`) that I need to replace in each email that goes with that mail address.

The code finds the two key words in the OFT file but just removes them or replaces them with a null entry.

What am I doing wrong, so that I can replace the words from the excel file in the OFT mail message.

The VBA I have in the excel sheet is:

```
Sub RunEmails()
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rngCell As Range

    For Each rngCell In Range("A2", "A" & CStr(Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row))
        Call DoTest(rngCell.Offset(0, 1).Value, "JDoe@abc.com", rngCell.Offset(0, 2).Value, rngCell.Value)
    Next rngCell

End Sub

Sub DoTest(EmailAddress As String, CCAddress As String, RecordToBeDeleted As String, UserName As String)
    Dim oApp As New Outlook.Application

    Dim olNewMail As Outlook.MailItem
    Const Template As String = "D:\Documents\list\list-mail.oft"

    Set olNewMail = oApp.CreateItemFromTemplate(Template)

    olNewMail.Recipients.Add EmailAddress
    olNewMail.HTMLBody = Replace(olNewMail.HTMLBody, ">UserName<", UserName)
    olNewMail.HTMLBody = Replace(olNewMail.HTMLBody, ">RecordToBeDeleted<", RecordToBeDeleted)
    olNewMail.VotingOptions = "Can distribution list be Deleted YES;Can distribution list be Deleted NO"

    olNewMail.Send
End Sub
```

Comment: I used the following - it worked!

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9147345/error-in-sending-mail-through-outlook-using-vb#new-answer?newreg=b23a1b588c6a4ba09b18ec756a34347b

Answer (score 0):

It seems that values for `UserName` and `RecordToBeDeleted` in `DoTest` (and other variables) are empty, since you call sub from the main procedure, but arguments are passed `ByRef` - or **by reference**, and this is by default. In your case that means you get what you have - since they're NOT declared / assigned in `RunEmails`, `ByRef` value is empty as well. In your case use `ByVal` arguments:

```
Sub DoTest(ByVal EmailAddress As String, ByVal CCAddress As String, ByVal RecordToBeDeleted As String, ByVal UserName As String)
```

Read more: [Passing Arguments by Value or by Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa164263%28v=office.10%29.aspx).

Hope that was helpful.

Comment: thanks for the info, I replaced that line but still getting the same results, just empty replacements. I'm trying to read up on that but don't know much on VBA, this is the first one I've tried to create, so now just trying to get the values to be replaced.

Comment: In that case it would be nice to see your Excel file - I'm not sure it reads values correctly from it.

Comment: thanks for the info, I replaced that line but still getting the same results, just empty replacements. I'm trying to read up on that but don't know much on VBA, this is the first one I've tried to create, so now just trying to get the values to be replaced